# APEX making HTTP Request, and It fails

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, session

I'm trying to make an http request, with the `UserInfo.getSessionID()`,  in the `authorization` value, to

```
https://{{INSTANCE}}.salesforce.com/services/data/v43/ui-api/record-ui/{{sObjectID}}
```

and It replies the following.

```
System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. 
Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"
```

What I'm trying to do, is to make some REST calls, to the same instance, because of some objects I can't get access with Apex.

How could I do this?
I tried doing it like this [article](https://rajvakati.com/2018/01/28/salesforce-ui-api-lightning-examples/), but it uses some urls for the callbacks, and I couldn't got it to work when I adapted the example to my instance.

Is this maybe because of a feature I need to activate for my sandbox? (I'm working in a sandbox)

Comment: Instead of 'v43' can you try 'v43.0'  ? Also can you make sure {{sObjectID}} is a valid Id of record present in the org?

Comment: Also are you able to access the above url on https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You should add your first comment as an answer.

Comment: It's a valid ID, and I changed the 43 to 43.0, and still nothing, the same problem persist, I tried with 42-44, and nothing I still get the same error, I tested all the request I need, and how to extract the data, with the workbench, but I can't connect with apex.

Answer (score 2):

The UI API Base URL is :

```
https://{{INSTANCE}}.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/ui-api/record-ui/{{sObjectID}}
```

Apparently, in the documentation, they have mentioned as

```
https://{your_instance}.salesforce.com/services/data/v{api_version}/ui-api
```

{api_version} is 42.0 , 43.0,44.0 etc

src:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm